# PHP file not working on hosting

Tags: php, networking, ftp

So this is what's happening. I don't know how to explain this.

I made a software which uploads file to my website's FTP location. It's working as it should.

[image]

As you can see in the folder that inside public_html/phphostrot.rviews.xyz/user_rot/ there are 2 php files. But when i visit the url http://phphostrot.rviews.xyz/ i get a blank page with inder of / and nothing else. And if i try to access http://phphostrot.rviews.xyz/user_rot/ I get 404 error. Even the link to the file is not working. I don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a issue with the file permissions. Have you configured your server to serve files from your **public** directory.

> Try changing the ownership of the files to *www* or *apache*

Answer (score 1):

app, img, wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes?
check file permissions (+x), as  @atefth said, check owner.
check webserver config. and check apache/nginx logs